# imagemagick autonumber starting from 1

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick

I can do this to batch resize and rename images in a subfolder:

```
convert '*.jpg' -resize 256 small/image_%02d.jpg
```

it will create images starting from `image_00.jpg`

My problem is, due to import rules of an external service, **I need incremental number starting from** `image_01.jpg`

Does IM allow this?

Otherwise which is the smartest way to achieve this?

I'd `ls` and reverse `sort` then rename adding `1`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have never tried this but remember reading something about -scene.

```
convert '*.jpg' -resize 256 -scene 1 small/image_%02d.jpg
```

-scene value

set scene number.

This option sets the scene number of an image or the first image in an image sequence.

Comment: Thank you **very** much, I love this website and its users :)